# How to fetch records from two tables without common column using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Users table details

> userid values (abc,xyz,abc,sdf)

master table details

> (mid,priority)values(101,1),(102,2),(101,1),(103,1)

i need to count of  mid based on userid (userid is names of users) group by priority(priority is int ) grouping like case priority =1 then 'Open', priority =2 then 'closed' etc using CTE(common table expression)

```
Select * from users
userid
abc
xyz
abc
sdf


Select * from master
mid  Priority
101    1
102    2
101    1
103    1
```

(Priority 1= Open 2=Closed)

OUTPUT expected:

```
Userid  count(mid) Priority
abc     2          Open
xyz     1          Closed
sdf     1          Open
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Also explain the logic behind your desired output.

Comment: No relation between the tables? How do you know how to pair rows from them? What if there are different number or rows in the tables?

Comment: I imagine the [UserID] column exists in his "master table", but he didn't include it in his question, so who knows?  Clearly, there's something missing, since there is no relation between the two tables with the information provided.

Comment: What if one of abc's priority is 1 and another one is 2? And Userid equals to mid? What is abc, xyz...?

Comment: same user can have multiple   priority.  ex abc can have both priority.

Comment: @Shivashant does this tables have the same number of rows and the same order?

Comment: expected output is count of mid for all users which should group by priority

Comment: @Shivashant how you want to join "userid" with "mid"?

Comment: @Евгений Кондратенко yes tables have the same number of rows and same order

Comment: @Shivashant Do you know that the order in which the lines appear is not the same as the order in which you insert them?

Comment: @Евгений Кондратенко i want to count mid who have priority as open OUTPUT column userid mid(count) priority

Comment: @Shivashant I just trying to say, that order in your select query result can be different with the order in which you insert them to this 2 tables.

Comment: @ Евгений Кондратенко yes the order is diffferent

Comment: @Shivashant, so, what is the rule to join userid with mid?

Comment: @ Евгений Кондратенко i want to list the user and their count(mid) which should be group by priority

Comment: @Shivashant how you join abc with 101 and sdf with 103 for example?

Comment: @ Евгений Кондратенко select count(distinct master.mid)'test',
priority,list.users
from MASTER1, list
where  1=1      list is CTE

Comment: By definition this is impossible. Tables do not have an order, they are considered unordered sets. You have nothing in your data to provide a consistent order so it is impossible to join "row 1" from the users table to "row 1" from the master table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use db_test;
go
drop table dbo.users;
create table dbo.users
(
    userid varchar(max) not null
)
;

insert into dbo.users
values 
        ('abc'),
        ('xyz'),
        ('sdf')


create table dbo.master
(
    mid int not null,
    Priority int not null
)
;

insert into dbo.master
values
    (101,    1),
    (102,    2),
    (101,    1),
    (103,    1)
;

with cte1 as (
    select userid, row_number() over(order by userid asc) as rn 
    from dbo.users
), cte2 as (
    select mid, priority, dense_rank() over(order by mid asc) as rn
    from dbo.master
)
select a.userid, count(*) as [count(mid)], b.priority
from cte1 a join cte2 b on a.rn = b.rn
group by a.userid, b.priority
```